# Как узнать высоту текстового блока из другой $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Народ, возник такой вопрос. Нужно привязать высоту изображения к высоте текстового блока (элемент p). Проблема в том, что они находятся в разных $scope. Как лучше всего это сделать?
С Angular знаком не очень. Если на счет высоты все понятно (getBoundingClientRect), то с областями видимости еще не вполне разобрался

Comment: добавь пример разметки и твоего кода

Answer (score 1):

А можно пример кода? Если проблема в том, что они в разных контроллерах, то лучше использовать какой-нибудь sharedService, ну или на худой конец $rootScope

Answer (score 1):

**.outerHeight()**

```html
<div ng-repeat="whatever in items" outer-height></div>
```

```js
app.directive('outerHeight', function(){
  return{
    restrict:'A',
    link: function(scope, element){
       console.log(element.outerHeight()); 
    }
  };
});
```